# How to remove leading and trailing whitespace in a MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, field, removing-whitespace

I have a table with two fields (countries and ISO codes):

```
Table1

   field1 - e.g. 'Afghanistan' (without quotes)
   field2 - e.g. 'AF'(without quotes)
```

In some rows the second field has whitespace at the start and/or end, which is affecting queries.

```
Table1

   field1 - e.g. 'Afghanistan' (without quotes) 
   field2 - e.g. ' AF' (without quotes but with that space in front)
```

Is there a way (in SQL) to go through the table and find/replace the whitespace in field2?

Comment: Adding my answer as comment to make it more visible: Just to be clear, TRIM by default only remove spaces (not all whitespaces). Here is the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Answer (score 339, accepted):

You're looking for [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

```
UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(FIELD2);
```

---

Seems like it might be worth it to mention that TRIM can support multiple types of whitespace, but only one at a time and it will use a space by default. You can, however, nest `TRIM`s.

```
 TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM column))
```

If you really want to get rid of *all* the whitespace in one call, you're better off using `REGEXP_REPLACE` along with the `[[:space:]]` notation. Here is an example:

```sql
SELECT 
    -- using concat to show that the whitespace is actually removed.
    CONCAT(
         '+', 
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
             '    ha ppy    ', 
             -- This regexp matches 1 or more spaces at the beginning with ^[[:space:]]+
             -- And 1 or more spaces at the end with [[:space:]]+$
             -- By grouping them with `()` and splitting them with the `|`
             -- we match all of the expected values.
             '(^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$)', 

             -- Replace the above with nothing
             ''
         ), 
         '+') 
    as my_example;
-- outputs +ha ppy+
```

Comment: Note: this only removes regular spaces and not other whitespace characters (tab, newline, etc)

Comment: yes you're right @TM so it's better to use:
UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(FIELD2,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r','')); etc.

Comment: Though @ChrisSim's solution will replace newlines and tabs WITHIN the content too, of course -- which probably isn't what most people want from a TRIM function!

Comment: UPDATE table T1 SET field = (SELECT replace(field, ' ', '') FROM table T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.id);

This should work since TRIM doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 51):

A general answer that I composed from your answers and from other links and it worked for me and I wrote it in a comment is:

```
 UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(FIELD2,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));
```

etc.

Because trim() doesn't remove all the white spaces so it's better to replace all the white spaces u want and than trim it.

Hope I could help you with sharing my answer :)

Comment: This removes all tabs/newlines. TRIM should only remove whitespace at either end of the string.

Comment: this a good idea of thinking and removing the new line characters, thanks , Works like a charm,i have upvoted it , bcoz for this thinking @Chris Sim

Answer (score 19):

Just to be clear, TRIM by default **only remove spaces** (not all whitespaces). Here is the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: This should be added as a comment.

Answer (score 14):

Please understand the use case before using this solution:

trim does not work while doing select query

This works

```
select replace(name , ' ','') from test;
```

While this doesn't

```
select trim(name) from test;
```

Comment: This should work: `select trim(name) name from test;`

Comment: `TRIM()` works fine for me in a `SELECT` statement, I'm really curious as to why this answer's got so many upvotes.  Are you using mysql?  What version?

Comment: trim remove leading and trailing spaces only http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: This is not ideal for name containing two words with space separator. Ex:- "Hong Kong" will become "HongKong".

Comment: Yeah this answer is wrong. How did this get 50+ upvotes?

Comment: This is not only wrong, it's dangerous. It can seriously garble someone's data.

Comment: I downvoted. Testcase: `SELECT CONCAT('"', TRIM(" hello world "), '"') AS \`trimmed value\` FROM DUAL` gives the wanted output `"hello world"`. While the replace variant dangerously removes the space as word separator: `SELECT CONCAT('"', REPLACE(" hello world ", ' ', '')) AS \`replaced value\` FROM DUAL`  gives the unwanted output `"helloworld"`

Comment: TRIM(name) does work, just only on CHAR(20) (the space character) unless specified differently. TRIM will remove only one specific character.

Answer (score 12):

It seems none of the current answers will actually remove 100% of whitespace from the start and end of a string.

As mentioned in other posts, the default [`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) only removes spaces - not tabs, formfeeds etc. A combination of `TRIM`s specifying other whitespace characters may provide a limited improvement e.g. `TRIM(BOTH '\r' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\f' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM TRIM(txt)))))`. But the problem with this approach is only a single character can be specified for a particular `TRIM` and those characters are only removed from the start and end. So if the string being trimmed is something like `\t \t \t \t` (i.e. alternate spaces and tab characters), more `TRIM`s would be needed - and in the general case this could go on indefinitely.

For a lightweight solution, it should be possible to write a simple User Defined Function (UDF) to do the job by looping through the characters at the start and end of a string. But I'm not going to do that... as I've already written a rather more heavyweight [regular expression replacer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826#38660574) which can also do the job - and may come in useful for other reasons, as described in [this blog post](http://stevettt.blogspot.co.uk/2018/02/a-mysql-regular-expression-replace.html).

**Demo**

[Rextester online demo](http://rextester.com/ICFQX34880). In particular, the last row shows the other methods failing but the regular expression method succeeding.

**Function**:

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- USAGE
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SELECT reg_replace(<subject>,
--                    <pattern>,
--                    <replacement>,
--                    <greedy>,
--                    <minMatchLen>,
--                    <maxMatchLen>);
-- where:
-- <subject> is the string to look in for doing the replacements
-- <pattern> is the regular expression to match against
-- <replacement> is the replacement string
-- <greedy> is TRUE for greedy matching or FALSE for non-greedy matching
-- <minMatchLen> specifies the minimum match length
-- <maxMatchLen> specifies the maximum match length
-- (minMatchLen and maxMatchLen are used to improve efficiency but are
--  optional and can be set to 0 or NULL if not known/required)
-- Example:
-- SELECT reg_replace(txt, '^[Tt][^ ]* ', 'a', TRUE, 2, 0) FROM tbl;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS reg_replace;
CREATE FUNCTION reg_replace(subject VARCHAR(21845), pattern VARCHAR(21845),
  replacement VARCHAR(21845), greedy BOOLEAN, minMatchLen INT, maxMatchLen INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(21845) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN 
  DECLARE result, subStr, usePattern VARCHAR(21845); 
  DECLARE startPos, prevStartPos, startInc, len, lenInc INT;
  IF subject REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET result = '';
    -- Sanitize input parameter values
    SET minMatchLen = IF(minMatchLen < 1, 1, minMatchLen);
    SET maxMatchLen = IF(maxMatchLen < 1 OR maxMatchLen > CHAR_LENGTH(subject),
                         CHAR_LENGTH(subject), maxMatchLen);
    -- Set the pattern to use to match an entire string rather than part of a string
    SET usePattern = IF (LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^', pattern, CONCAT('^', pattern));
    SET usePattern = IF (RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$', usePattern, CONCAT(usePattern, '$'));
    -- Set start position to 1 if pattern starts with ^ or doesn't end with $.
    IF LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^' OR RIGHT(pattern, 1) <> '$' THEN
      SET startPos = 1, startInc = 1;
    -- Otherwise (i.e. pattern ends with $ but doesn't start with ^): Set start position
    -- to the min or max match length from the end (depending on "greedy" flag).
    ELSEIF greedy THEN
      SET startPos = CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - maxMatchLen + 1, startInc = 1;
    ELSE
      SET startPos = CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - minMatchLen + 1, startInc = -1;
    END IF;
    WHILE startPos >= 1 AND startPos <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
      AND startPos + minMatchLen - 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
      AND !(LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^' AND startPos <> 1)
      AND !(RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$'
            AND startPos + maxMatchLen - 1 < CHAR_LENGTH(subject)) DO
      -- Set start length to maximum if matching greedily or pattern ends with $.
      -- Otherwise set starting length to the minimum match length.
      IF greedy OR RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$' THEN
        SET len = LEAST(CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - startPos + 1, maxMatchLen), lenInc = -1;
      ELSE
        SET len = minMatchLen, lenInc = 1;
      END IF;
      SET prevStartPos = startPos;
      lenLoop: WHILE len >= 1 AND len <= maxMatchLen
                 AND startPos + len - 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
                 AND !(RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$' 
                       AND startPos + len - 1 <> CHAR_LENGTH(subject)) DO
        SET subStr = SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, len);
        IF subStr REGEXP usePattern THEN
          SET result = IF(startInc = 1,
                          CONCAT(result, replacement), CONCAT(replacement, result));
          SET startPos = startPos + startInc * len;
          LEAVE lenLoop;
        END IF;
        SET len = len + lenInc;
      END WHILE;
      IF (startPos = prevStartPos) THEN
        SET result = IF(startInc = 1, CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, 1)),
                        CONCAT(SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, 1), result));
        SET startPos = startPos + startInc;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;
    IF startInc = 1 AND startPos <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject) THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(result, RIGHT(subject, CHAR_LENGTH(subject) + 1 - startPos));
    ELSEIF startInc = -1 AND startPos >= 1 THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(LEFT(subject, startPos), result);
    END IF;
  ELSE
    SET result = subject;
  END IF;
  RETURN result;
END;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS format_result;
CREATE FUNCTION format_result(result VARCHAR(21845))
RETURNS VARCHAR(21845) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
  RETURN CONCAT(CONCAT('|', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(result, '\t', '\\t'), CHAR(12), '\\f'), '\r', '\\r'), '\n', '\\n')), '|');
END;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl;
CREATE TABLE tbl
AS
SELECT 'Afghanistan' AS txt
UNION ALL
SELECT ' AF' AS txt
UNION ALL
SELECT ' Cayman Islands  ' AS txt
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('\t \t ', CHAR(12)), ' \r\n\t British Virgin Islands \t \t  ', CHAR(12)), ' \r\n') AS txt;     

SELECT format_result(txt) AS txt,
       format_result(TRIM(txt)) AS trim,
       format_result(TRIM(BOTH '\r' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\f' FROM TRIM(BOTH '\t' FROM TRIM(txt))))))
         AS `trim spaces, tabs, formfeeds and line endings`,
       format_result(reg_replace(reg_replace(txt, '^[[:space:]]+', '', TRUE, 1, 0), '[[:space:]]+$', '', TRUE, 1, 0))
         AS `reg_replace`
FROM tbl;
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT reg_replace(
         reg_replace(txt,
                     '^[[:space:]]+',
                     '',
                     TRUE,
                     1,
                     0),
         '[[:space:]]+$',
         '',
         TRUE,
         1,
         0) AS `trimmed txt`
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: that's pretty impressive! On MySQL 8+ one can use the new `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

Answer (score 4):

This statement will remove and update the field content of your database

To remove whitespaces in the left side of the field value

**UPDATE table SET field1 = LTRIM(field1);**

ex. UPDATE member SET firstName = LTRIM(firstName);

To remove whitespaces in the right side of the field value

**UPDATE table SETfield1 = RTRIM(field1);**

ex. UPDATE member SET firstName = RTRIM(firstName);

Answer (score 4):

I needed to trim the values in a primary key column that had first and last names, so I did not want to trim all white space as that would remove the space between the first and last name, which I needed to keep. What worked for me was...

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `FIELD`= TRIM(FIELD);
```

or

```
UPDATE 'TABLE' SET 'FIELD' = RTRIM(FIELD);
```

or

```
UPDATE 'TABLE' SET 'FIELD' = LTRIM(FIELD);
```

Note that the first instance of FIELD is in single quotes but the second is not in quotes at all. I had to do it this way or it gave me a syntax error saying it was a duplicate primary key when I had both in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use trim in select query, you can also use regular expressions

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field RLIKE ' * query-string *'
```

return rows with field like '      query-string   '

Answer (score 0):

you can use ltrim or rtrim to clean whitespaces for the right or left or a string.

Answer (score -5):

I know its already accepted, but for thoses like me who look for "remove ALL whitespaces" (not just at the begining and endingof the string):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('1234 243', ' ', 1);
// returns '1234'
```

**EDIT 2019/6/20 :** Yeah, that's not good.  The function returns the part of the string since "when the character space occured for the first time".
So, I guess that saying this remove the leading and trailling whitespaces and returns the first word :

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(' 1234 243'), ' ', 1);
```

Comment: This has no relevance to the OP.

Comment: Whoah, you're not removing *all whitespaces* - you are removing *everything from the first space onward*.