# remove whitespaces on query mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Inside my database table called `Postcodes` I have rows like `AB10 1AB`, `AB10 2AB`

so when I'm pulling them to access a dynamic page they're appearing in the URL like `AB10%201AB` obviously because or being URL encoded, now how can I set the URL to just `AB101AB` and then still access the database row using `AB101AB`?

in brief, I want to access a row inside a database which has a value of `AB10 1AB` using `AB101AB`

something like

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `Postcodes` 
WHERE 
    `postcode` = REMOVEWHITESPACES FROM `postcode` ROW('AB101AB')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - how to remove white space in a mysql field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858143/mysql-how-to-remove-white-space-in-a-mysql-field)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace()` function (reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)):

```
select *
from `Postcodes`
where replace(`postcode`, ' ', '') = 'AB101AB'
```