# How to remove multiple whitespaces, new lines, carriage return, and tab in a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replace, tabs, whitespace, carriage-return

How do you perform the following **PHP** function in **MySQL** using `UPDATE`, `SET` and `REPLACE`?

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

from [Remove multiple whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php)

**EDIT QUESTION**

My objectif is to go from the follwing string

```
[!DOCTYPE html]
[!--[if IE 8]][html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="es" ][![endif]--]
[!--[if gt IE 8]][!--] [html class="no-js" lang="es" ] [!--[![endif]--]
[html lang="es-ES" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"]
[head]
```

to the above

```
[!DOCTYPE html][!--[if IE 8]][html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="es" ][![endif]--]
[!--[if gt IE 8]][!--][html class="no-js" lang="es" ][!--[![endif]--][html lang="es-ES" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"][head]
```

clearing all the **\r \n \t**

\n = new line
\r = carriage return
\t = tab

**EDIT ANSWER**

The full answer using `UPDATE`, `SET` and `REPLACE` in addition to Elias Van Ootegem's suggestion

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(col, '~', ''), 
                '\t', '' -- replace tabs
            ),
            '\n','' -- replace *NIX line-feeds
        ),
        '\r', -- replace DOS line-feeds
        ''
    )
```

Comment: Have you even tried... there's thousands of dupes for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858143/mysql-how-to-remove-white-space-in-a-mysql-field

Comment: it is no what I want...

Comment: Added answer, hopefully that's what you were after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace *all* whitespace chars from any string in mysql, you'll have to call `REPLACE` a couple of times:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(fieldName, ' ', ''), -- replace spaces
                '\t', '' -- replace tabs
            ),
            '\n','' -- replace *NIX line-feeds
        ),
        '\r', -- replace DOS line-feeds
        ''
    );
```

That should cover them all. If I forgot about one, just add another `REPLACE( /*replace calls here*/, '~', '')`, to add that to the list.
MySQL isn't that good at processing text, though, so whatever you'll attempt, it'll feel a tad clunky

Answer (score 0):

You can try trim and replace function

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = TRIM( `col_name` )

UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE( `col_name` , ' ' , '' )
```

I hope it may solve the problems

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but TRIM or REPLACE doesn't clear all the whitespaces (\r\n\t) in between the string

Comment: sorry can you edit your answer so I can vote you up?