# how to exclude white spaces in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an excel sheet for insert statement, in excel sheet there is no white spaces, but when inserted in mysql database. the insertion is successful but the data have white spaces in it.

how to excluded?

Regards:

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858143/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a different answer I.E. SQL based.

```
SELECT TRIM(' leading trailing ')
```

To use in an INSERT you could

```
INSERT INTO Users (forename, surname) VALUES (TRIM(' ASHLEY '), TRIM(' MEDWAY '))
```

Comment: trim didn't work: INSERT INTO tbl_business ( name, description, address_1, address_2, location, region,  country_iso, contact_person, postal_code, ph_office, ph_cell, fax, email, website, category_id,  user_id, is_approved) VALUES                     (TRIM(' this is name '),TRIM(' this is desc '), ' this is address 1 ',' thisis address 2 ', 69 , 1 ,' PK ',' thi sis contact person ',' 44000 ',' 3434343 ',' this is cell ',' this is fax ',' admin@email.com ',' www.google.com ', 1 ,1,1);

Comment: there is no error, the white spaces also inserted. I want to not insert these.

Answer (score 2):

Either http://php.net/trim or http://php.net/str_replace?
As in: `str_replace ( ' ' , '' , $str );`

Comment: This needs a lot more work as IMO the OP would not know how to implement this into a solution

Comment: If OP doesn't give more of his source code, this is the most I can do to help him...

Comment: don't know IMO and OP. what these stands for?

Comment: In my opinion and opening post/original poster.
More importantly: did my solution help you?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP `trim()` function

https://www.php.net/trim

```
<?php
$str="   This is a test";
echo trim($str);
?>
```

Comment: this is needed in insert statement. mysql

Comment: @Muhammad Definitely!

Answer (score -1):

copy queries from excel to notepad/textpad and remove white/tab spaces by CTRL+H. and run the the statements. basically excel adds tab white spaces between columns. in case of strings, tab spaces are added in between double quotes("").

Comment: but I need to collect the data in excel sheet and then copy and paste to mysql console. is there any way to trim these spaces.