# Where condition do not work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a query in mysql.

```
 SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE colName = "name";
```

However, no records are selected. I checked the table and there are fields that matched the condition. By the way, the records are inserted by a stored procedure. When I tried to edit some records (colName column), the edited records are selected. colName has a datatype varchar

Comment: Looks like white space issue, run this first `update tablename set colName = trim(colName)` then try your select query and see if it does anything.

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: Can you show some sample data from the table, including records that match?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE colName LIKE '%name%';

Comment: your data probably has whitespace in it you're not aware of

Comment: When I tried to edit the field, there is no other spaces. Does this still have white spaces?

Comment: I cannot use LIKE because i need to have the exact value..

Comment: Do you execute a commit after the inserts?

Comment: what do you mean commit?

Comment: @ Abhik Chakraborty: I tried to remove the whitespaces in my table by updating that column. I used SET colName = Trim(colName) However it says that no rows affected

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if you will get any results and check if you have issues with white spaces or something...

```
SELECT *,LENGTH(colName) FROM tblName WHERE colName LIKE "%name%";
```

There is also the possibility ( i have this issue my self on application i use) that characters that match your language are 'translated' in you data e.g for Greek :
GEORGE seems the same with GΕΟRGΕ But there are NOT when you convert them to lower case

```
gεοrgε  <> george
```

Comment: Hi John, yes i got some columns that have my expected length. I've tried to update the columns by SET colName = TRIM(colName) however it always says 0 affected rows

Comment: is there any chance for the problem i mentioned ? do you have multi language data..the best thing to allow quick and accurate response is to provide a SQLFiddle.

Comment: im sorry but what do you mean multi language? I have tried to selecting Lower(colName), it was translated well

Comment: is English your native language ? also take note that mySQL is case sensitive

Comment: yeah. english. in my select query, it says that it has 4 characters however what is visible is only 3. I tried to update it by the use of TRIM however it did not work. it always says no rows affected.

Comment: export some data to SQLFiddle...this will help solving it

Comment: @san-san try using HEX() function on the text - it will show you byte values for those invisible characters so you will know what they are

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure

but please try to use single quote instead double quote

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE colName = 'name';
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me a lot. I haven't noticed that i have some other whitespace in my field.

[How to remove leading and trailing whitespace in a MySQL field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858143/mysql-how-to-remove-white-space-in-a-mysql-field#comment31615187_6858168)