# search by the name without including space or with space

Tags: mysql

the user saved on database `ahmedhatem`

```
SELECT personal_data.fname
    FROM
    personal_data
    WHERE
    ( personal_data.fname  LIKE '%ahmed hatem%' or
    Replace(ahmed hatem , ' ', '')
      LIKE '%ahmed hatem%'
```

when i use `ahmedhatem`  the result going well 
but i need this sql to find the  `ahmedhatem`
what can i do ?
i tried to use

```
personal_data.fname 
  LIKE '%ahmed hatem%'
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question as already been asked.
[How to remove leading and trailing whitespace in a MySQL field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858143/mysql-how-to-remove-white-space-in-a-mysql-field)
You can use `TRIM()` function.

Comment: but i need to remove the spaces from the result come from form filed .. and change ahmed hatem with $name  that mean if the user start to search about ahmed hatem and the name in tha database saved as ahmedhatem he can find it .. i tried trim but i didn't got the result

Comment: This is working for me `SELECT * FROM 'personal_data' WHERE fname LIKE replace('ahmed hatem', ' ','')`
You can even add % `SELECT * FROM 'personal_data' WHERE fname LIKE replace('%med hatem', ' ','')`

Answer (score 0):

You can you percent sign as "any amount of any characters" wherever you want

```
SELECT personal_data.fname
FROM
personal_data
WHERE
 personal_data.fname  LIKE '%ahmed%hatem%'
```

Comment: but i need to make this  LIKE '%ahmed%hatem%' but from text field it will be LIKE '%$name%' haw can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to remove all whitespaces