# Correlate 2 columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, image, identity-column

```
SELECT ica.CORP_ID, ica.CORP_IDB, ica.ITEM_ID, ica.ITEM_IDB, 
ica.EXP_ACCT_NO, ica.SUB_ACCT_NO, ica.PAT_CHRG_NO, ica.PAT_CHRG_PRICE, 
ica.TAX_JUR_ID, ica.TAX_JUR_IDB, ITEM_PROFILE.COMDTY_NAME
FROM ITEM_CORP_ACCT ica
,ITEM_PROFILE
WHERE (ica.CORP_ID = 1000) 
AND (ica.CORP_IDB = 4051) 
AND (ica.ITEM_ID = 1000) 
AND (ica.ITEM_IDB = 4051)
AND ica.EXP_ACCT_NO = ITEM_PROFILE.EXP_ACCT_NO
```

I'm trying basically say since the exp account code is '801500' then the Name should return "Miscellaneous Medic...".

[image]

Comment: Can you give a minimal example and formulate a question?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: @Dschoni _Can_ they or _will_ they?  Not the same thing unfortunately for us.

Comment: `SELECT .. CASE ica.EXP_ACCT_NO WHEN  '801500'  THEN 'Miscellaneous Medic...' ELSE ITEM_PROFILE.COMDTY_NAME END AS  COMDTY_NAME FROM ..` I believe

Comment: I dont see any question.   Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Belal Kamara How is it going in order to find an answer? Did you find what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if what you are showing is not possible. Have you edited the data in the editor??? You are joining using `ica.EXP_ACCT_NO = ITEM_PROFILE.EXP_ACCT_NO` . Therefore, every entry with EXP_ACCT_NO = 801500, should also have the same `COMDTY_NAME`.

However, it could be the case that your IDs are not actually numbers and that they are strings with whitespace (`801500__` vs `801500` ). But since you are not performing a left-outer join, it would also mean you have an entry in `ITEM_PROFILE` with the same whitespace.

You also need to properly normalize your table data (unless this is a view) but it still means you have erroneous data.

Try to perform the same query, but using the `TRIM` function to remove whitespace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6858168/1688441 .

**Example:**

```
SELECT ica.CORP_ID, ica.CORP_IDB, ica.ITEM_ID, ica.ITEM_IDB, 
ica.EXP_ACCT_NO, ica.SUB_ACCT_NO, ica.PAT_CHRG_NO, ica.PAT_CHRG_PRICE, 
ica.TAX_JUR_ID, ica.TAX_JUR_IDB, ITEM_PROFILE.COMDTY_NAME
FROM ITEM_CORP_ACCT ica
,ITEM_PROFILE
WHERE (ica.CORP_ID = 1000) 
AND (ica.CORP_IDB = 4051) 
AND (ica.ITEM_ID = 1000) 
AND (ica.ITEM_IDB = 4051)
```

> ```
> AND trim(ica.EXP_ACCT_NO) = trim(ITEM_PROFILE.EXP_ACCT_NO);
> ```