# MySQL: TRIM spaces and newlines from both sides

Tags: mysql, regex

MySQL has a built-in function TRIM() that can remove spaces and newlines one at a time from both sides of a string. However, to remove alternate spaces and newlines (ex: ' \r\n \r \n foo bar \r\n \r \n ') would require several loops of TRIM, which could be done via WHILE DO in a function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`localhost` FUNCTION `trim_all`(`_s1` TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
    NO SQL
BEGIN

    DECLARE _s2 TEXT DEFAULT '';

    WHILE( CHAR_LENGTH(_s1) != CHAR_LENGTH(_s2) ) DO
        SET _s2 = _s1;
        SET _s1 = TRIM(TRIM('\r' FROM TRIM('\n' FROM _s1)));
    END WHILE;

    RETURN _s1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Although this function works (so far), it seems to be an over complication for such a simple task. Besides, such WHILE DO loops can be dangerous.

**Questions**

1. Any idea how to optimize this code? Any foreseen bug?
2. Any other idea how to do such trim without WHILE DO loops? Regex?

---

**Notes:**

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"
version     5.6.39-83.1
```

Therefore, `REGEXP_REPLACE` is not available.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a better solution:

```
 UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(FIELD2,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));
```

Copied from this other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23807798/236528

Comment: Your code removes all the occurrences of newlines. This is a different behavior than the one I've described.